# Google sheets return a string of concatenated values from a range based on value

Tags: google-sheets

I appreciate this question might be on the incorrect Stackexchange website but this is the one I frequent most often and wasn't sure of a more appropriate one - so feel free to move it mods if required.

Basically I have the following scenario:

[image: problem]

What I'm trying to do in Google sheets is write a formula which will return me a concatenated string of the name of players that need items, in the cell which corresponds with the boss. E.g. B9 would read "Player 2, Player 4" C9 would read "Player 3, Player 4".

Unsure if this is even possible in Google Sheets; I'm sure it is but could use a helpful pointer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's interesting I don't know a way of doing it in Excel because the concatenate function doesn't work with arrays, but you can do it in Google Sheets:-

```
=ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(IF(B4:B7<>"",$A4:$A7&" ","")))
```

(this is almost what you want - uses a space instead of a comma as separator).

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was after. I had to change the "IF" to a not-equals operator "<>" because I wanted the list of people that DID need items. Not that I'm complaining! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see what you mean! Thank you for feedback and comma separator improvement.

Comment: An afterthought - could use this to avoid #VALUE error if strings are all empty =mid(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(IF(B4:B7<>ʺʺ,ʺ, ʺ&$A4:$A7,ʺʺ))),3,999)