# INDEX MATCH function with multiple results

Tags: excel, function

I have a table containing monster names in row 1. Below there are colors in each row. I need a formula that is looking in row 2 for "green" and for every match it should print the related monster name separated by comma. In this case:

```
MONSTER1   MONSTER2  MONSTER3
GREEN                GREEN
           BLUE      BLUE
RED                  RED
PURPLE     PURPLE    PURPLE
```

For the color green the formula should print: "MONSTER1, MONSTER3".
For the color purple: "MONSTER1, MONSTER2, MONSTER3"

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a out of the box function.  You'll need VBA to get that.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible if I am not looking for a specific color but only if the cell is empty or not? And for every cell that is not empty, it should print the monsters name(s)?

Comment: I think I've answered a similar question in Google Sheets. It's easier in Google Sheets because it allows concatenation with arrays, which Excel doesn't.

Comment: The issue here is not to look for "GREEN", but concatenating content from several cells into one, it can't be done with standards formulas.

Comment: Here is the Google Sheets one if you're interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562744/google-sheets-return-a-string-of-concatenated-values-from-a-range-based-on-value/28563838#28563838